# Is my logging-module thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, file-io, mfc

Guys, I am a beginner in threading and logging. 
Btw, I am not a native English speaker, so pardon me if there is any mistake in my English.

I have created a **multiple-thread** software, where each thread uses **logging module** like the following:
Each thread uses different log files, so I believe that the chances of data conflicts occurred are 0.

```
__inline void print_logW(int _level,const wchar_t *domain,const wchar_t *msg)
{
    wchar_t mess[200] = _T("");

    if(_level<=traceLevel)
    {
        __time64_t timer;
        struct tm t_st;
        _time64(&timer);

        localtime_s(&t_st,&timer);

        if (domain == NULL)
        {
            domain = _T("");
        }
        if (msg != NULL)
        {
            if (showTimeStampFlag == true)
            {
                swprintf_s(mess,200,_T("%s : %ld"),msg,GetTickCount());
            }
            else
            {
                wcscpy_s(mess,200,msg);
            }
        }

        if(oldTime.tm_year != t_st.tm_year || oldTime.tm_mon != t_st.tm_mon || oldTime.tm_mday != t_st.tm_mday) 
        {
            oldTime = t_st;
            print_log_preparebyDateW();
        }


        FILE* fp;
        errno_t err = _wfopen_s(&fp, this->m_pathW, _T("at+, ccs=UTF-8"));
        if (err != 0)
        {
            // error
            return;
        }

        fwprintf_s(fp, m_logFormatW,
            _level,
            1900 + t_st.tm_year, t_st.tm_mon + 1, t_st.tm_mday,
            t_st.tm_hour, t_st.tm_min, t_st.tm_sec,
            domain, mess
            );
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

When I see the log of the software that I made, I found a problem where sometimes the thread process becomes so slow (a process (such as getting pointer of an image) that usually only take **16 ms max**, would take **0.2 seconds** or more to finish). I am still investigating the cause of this problem, but at first, I would like to know whether the logging module is already thread safe or not.

By the way, for the parameters, 
`"_level"` is the logging level to print or unprint the details of the process
I use `"domain"` to show the class where the logging is performed
`"msg"` is the content of the log (e.g. "process 1 started")

And as for the `m_logFormatW`,

```
m_logFormatW = _T("[%.2d][%.4d-%.2d-%.2dT%.2d:%.2d:%.2d][%s] %s\n");
```

If there is any question or anything unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Where does "oldTime" come from? Does each thread have its own instance of the class that contains the function? FWIW: You might want to use "%u" when you know a value is unsigned. For instance, you are using 32-bit millisecond timestamps which going to become negative for 24.85 days out of every 49.7, but you print them as "%ld" so it's going to go ahead and slap a minus sign in there :)

Comment: constant opening and closing `fp` is very expensive. To quicken your logging: use a large buffer (32k?) and write it only when it is getting full; handle all signals and make sure you flush and close the log file in their handlers. Your way is much safer though.

Comment: @kfsone : Thank you for the suggestion. I will change the format from "%ld" to "%u". And about the "oldTime", it's actually a property of the logger class that has "struct tm" as it's data type

Comment: @Dariusz : Thank you, I thought about doing so too, but since the software sometimes crashes, I want to be able to know what process that made it crash, so I don't think the log buffering and flushing is a good idea.

Comment: @LinardiKurniawan you complained about the logging being slow, so I pointed out a few reasons. What you do with it is your own choice :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are linking to the [multi-threaded runtime libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) and `oldTime` is not a global or static variable your log function will be thread safe. If `oldTime` is a global or static variable you will need to serialize access to it when you access or modify it otherwise you risk a race condition. The only other thing that *may* not be thread safe is `print_log_preparebyDateW` but it's hard to say since you haven't included the code for it. As long as `oldTime` is not global or static and all the runtime library functions that you use are marked as thread safe or are part of a library marked as thread safe in the MSDN you'll be OK.

The only other problem I can see is when you open the file. If the file is already open and another thread attempts to log information the open call will fail causing the information to be lost. This is because [`_wfopen_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) opens the file without any sharing modes. You can fix this by using [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and locking it while the file is open and unlocking it after the file is closed.

One possible reason your worker threads are taking longer to execute than expected is that opening the log file, writing the information, flushing the file and closing it can take a bit of extra time. This can happen any time file I/O occurs even when caching is involved. Usually you can reduce the time by opening the log file once and then closing it when your application terminates.

Another possible solution to reduce the time it takes your worker threads to execute is to use a pipe. In this scenario you write the log text to a pipe and have an additional thread that reads from the pipe and writes to the log file. This will eliminate any disk I/O that may occur when your worker threads log information. You may encounter some instances where the logging takes a bit of extra time if the pipe is full but it won't happen as often.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good for single threaded application and will not work in multithreaded environment  as you are not serializing the log message requests.

Its better you look into some well written logger class in opensource such as

a) AsynchronousAndSynchronouslogger -  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288827/g2log-An-efficient-asynchronous-logger-using-Cplus

b) Simplethreadsafe - http://cpplogging.codeplex.com/

c) Log4Cpp - http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: "not serializing the log message requests" has nothing to do with this code being thread safe. And since he is opening the file in "at+" mode and uses single printf his writes are guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: If this function is not serialized. The logs doesn't gets printed based on time stamp.

Comment: @shivakumar : Thank you for the recommendations. Since I want to catch the moment before the application crashes, I prefer to use a synchronous logger.

Thus, I am thinking about trying the (b) Simplethreadsafe, and also after I searched on the net, I also found a thread-safe logger called Legit Log C++ Library
(http://www.legitlog.com/Products/LegitLogCLibrary). By the way, have you tried Legit Log before ??

Comment: Never tried that library. It seems like a static lib. It would be good if its a dll.